# How to put space to text in <input>

Tags: html, css

I want to put left and right space to text inside of  as you can see on image. 
I was able to put left space with text-indent but it doesn't seem to work for right space.

Can anyone help me?
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8WIz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here inputs can have left right padding to act for indent.

```
input {padding: 0 5px}
```

So above inputs will carry 5px of space inside to both left and right.

Comment: in database space will get store?

Comment: you need to apply this in your css style somewhere, nothing to do with database

Answer (score 1):

if you want it in one text box then add `class` like below and use it in the `css`

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' class='space'>
    .space
    {
        padding-left : 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

If you want both side you can use `padding` only.If you use like this it will work when you have appropriate space in the window.If you want to keep the space in at any screen size you can use [border-box](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

```
.space
{
    padding-left : 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: this solution has no effect on my text input

Answer (score 0):

Well one option would be to combine text-indent with a padding if your markup allows it:

```
text-indent: 10px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

Another method I guess could be the "direction" attribute with a value of "rtl" in combination with "text-align:left".

Answer (score 0):

please try following code

```css
input{
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    border:1px solid #eaeaea;
    outline:none;
}
input:hover{
    border-color: #a0a0a0 #b9b9b9 #b9b9b9 #b9b9b9;
}
input:focus{
    border-color:#4d90fe;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set some padding to your input text :

```
input {
  padding: 0 5px /* 0 is for top and bottom | 5px is for left and right */
}
```

Here the doc on the CSS padding property : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp